# Wrap all base calls in a derived type

Tags: c#

So I have a few instances where I'd like to be able to do this but essentially I'd like to be able to wrap all calls to a Superclass in a derived type. Right now I'm trying to wrap all calls to base method in an Impersonator but I can see other uses for this as well.

An example being

```
public void CopyFile(string filePath, string destPath)
{
  using(var I = new Impersonator("user", ".", "password"))
  {
     base.CopyFile(string filePath, string destPath);
  }
}
```

Another convenient use might be

```
public void CopyFile(string filePath, string destPath)
{
  try
  {
    base.CopyFile(string filePath, string destPath);
  } catch(Exception e)
  {
    Log(e.Message);
  }
}
```

Now I'd like to wrap all base calls similarly. Is there a convenient way to do this or do I have to wrap all of these manually?

I'm looking for something like a "foreach baseMethod in Superclass Do This"

Perhaps finding some way to capture incoming calls to the class and wrapping them as an action?

```
public void ActionWrapper(Action action)
{
  try
  {
    action.Invoke();
  } catch(Exception e)
  {
    Log(e.Message);
  }
}
```

But how would I catch calls to the class in that way?

Honestly this is just to make the class more maintainable and reduce code bloat. I'm open to these or any other approaches.

Comment: For case 1) you would probably use an override like GetImpersonator() in the base class instead. For case 2) i'd use a global error handler: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`

Comment: Didn't know there was such a thing for the UnhandledException! Will that do what I think it does? Catch any exception that falls through the cracks? That's amazing! I mean simply for logging it but I'm sure other uses would also come up.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the GetImpersonator()? I'd like to avoid altering the base class if I can but I'd like to make sure I'm hearing out the solution in its entirety and I feel like I'm not seeing the whole picture here.

Comment: are you asking about automatic wrapping each method for existing classes with loggin/exception handling ? Please try to check the [aspect oriented programming  paradigm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/february/aspect-oriented-programming-aspect-oriented-programming-with-the-realproxy-class) in such case. It can be implemented using the https://www.postsharp.net

Comment: Does the app use a Dependency Injection framework? If so, which one? Some DI frameworks have features designed to help with exactly this problem.

Comment: I'm seeking to provide this functionality via a DLL.

Comment: @oleksa I believe PostSharp is a paid for product? just thought it's worth mentioning in case OP decides to go that way

Comment: I'd **love** to learn to work with PostSharp but most of my code goes into my companies codebase in one form or another and I don't think it would fly in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I want to applaud your instinct to deconstruct code this way. Separating concerns like error handling/logging and security/identity from your business logic can do wonders for maintainability.

What you're describing is known as either [decoration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) or [interception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interceptor_pattern). Mark Seemann has [a good blog post](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/20/InstrumentationwithDecoratorsandInterceptors/) comparing the two approaches in the context of logging.

Without using external tools (like a DI or AOP framework), I think the `ActionWrapper` method you proposed is a good start. I modified it to show impersonation rather than logging, since I think impersonation is a more interesting use case:

```cs
public void ActionWrapper(Action action)
{
  using(var I = new Impersonator("user", ".", "password"))
  {
    action.Invoke();
  }
}
```

So the question is: How to apply this method efficiently?

Let's assume your existing class is:

```cs
public class FileCopier
{
    public void CopyFile(string filePath, string destPath)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

You could, as you suggested, create a derived class to add impersonation:

```cs
public class FileCopierWithImpersonation : FileCopier
{
    public void CopyFile(string filePath, string destPath)
        => WithImpersonation(base.CopyFile(filePath, destPath));

    public void WithImpersonation(Action action)
    {
      using(var I = new Impersonator("user", ".", "password"))
      {
        action.Invoke();
      }
    }
}
```

Here, `FileCopierWithImpersonation` serves as a decorator over `FileCopier`, implemented via inheritance. The `WithImpersonation` method serves as an interceptor that can apply an impersonation scope over any method.

That should work well enough, but it forces some compromises in implementation. The base class's methods will all need to be marked as `virtual`. The child class's constructor might need to pass arguments to the base class. It will be impossible to unit test the child class's logic independently of the base class's logic.

So, you might want to extract an interface (`IFileCopier`) and apply the decorator using composition rather than inheritance:

```cs
public class FileCopierWithImpersonation : IFileCopier
{
    private readonly IFileCopier _decoratee;

    public FileCopierWithImpersonation(IFileCopier decoratee)
    {
         // If you don't want to inject the dependency, you could also instantiate
         // it here: _decoratee = new FileCopier();
        _decoratee = decoratee;
    }

    public void CopyFile(string filePath, string destPath)
        => WithImpersonation(_decoratee.CopyFile(filePath, destPath));

    public void WithImpersonation(Action action)
    {
      using(var I = new Impersonator("user", ".", "password"))
      {
        action.Invoke();
      }
    }
}
```

If you're using Visual Studio 2019, there's a refactoring option to "Implement Interface through..." that will automatically implement an interface by calling methods of a dependency of the same type. After that, a simple find/replace should be all that's needed to add the interceptor.

[image: Animation of Visual Studio 2019 "Implement Interface Through..." refactoring]

You could also look into code generation tools, like [T4 Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates) to auto-generate the decorators. Beware, though, that T4 is not supported in .NET Core. It looks to be a legacy technology at this point.

Answer (score 1):

From a good design perspective, I would advise not to do this for 2 reasons:

1. If catching exception is the sole purpose, then don't do it. Catching and swallowing system exceptions is a bad practice
2. If you want to do some pre-setup or post-processing on every method of base then may be you should choose `composition` rather than `inheritance` here.

However, if you have made up your mind then using `an array of delegates` can solve your problem.

```
class Derived : Base
{
    private Action[] AllActions;

    public Derived()
    {
        AllActions = new Action[] 
        {
            base.DoSomething1,
            base.DoSomething2,
            base.DoSomethingMore
        };
    }

    public ActionWrapper(int index)
    {
        try
        {
            AllActions[index].Invoke();
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

For simplicity I have used an array. Use a dictionary to keep a key for each base class method.

Comment: This is a most excellent answer. 

I'm not seeking to suppress exceptions. The method I use is not identical but its at work and I don't have it in front of me. Each method has an optional parameter to throw on failure which defaults to true since that's the behavior most devs would expect.

Can you go a bit further into how you would use composition to provide this functionality?

Comment: @Imbaker1234 Composition is kind of using the Adapter Pattern. That way your code will be more expressive. Each class will have a specific purpose. However, in that way you will have to provide a wrapper method in your composition class for every method in your actual class.

Comment: A wiki link to the design principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, this will work only if base methods are with the same signature, which is a pretty low chance

Comment: @kuskmen I would say this particular implementation will work only if methods don't return anything. Adding generic Func might work but looks complicated

Comment: While this is an interesting answer I didn’t go with it as the best answer for this question. The issue being you have to call the actions using another method instead of the object itself. The end goal here is really to reduce code bloat/ boilerplate while leaving existing implementations unaltered. At the end of the day it looks like you can’t avoid wrapping calls if you want this kind of result but the answer provided by @Xander at least shows me a better way to wrap them.

Answer (score 1):

I see [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) has been suggested but not expanded upon, so I will attempt to cover it then. 
I am assuming you are open to making your base class methods `virtual`. In this case using a [Castle DynamicProxy](https://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) might give you the flexibility you are after. It will allow you to not only inject code before and after parent method execution, but also change input/output parameters depending on your business requirements.

Here's an artist's impression on what your class might look like should you opt for it:

```cs
public class FileCopier
{
    public virtual void CopyFile(string filePath, string destPath)
    {
        // do things here
    }
}

public class ImpersonationInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        using (var I = new Impersonator("user", ".", "password"))
        {           
            invocation.Proceed();
        }       
    }
}

public class LoggingInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        try
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
        }       
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log(e.Message);
        }
    }
}

public class CustomProxyGenerationHook : IProxyGenerationHook
{
    public void MethodsInspected() {}

    public void NonProxyableMemberNotification(Type type, MemberInfo memberInfo) {}

    public bool ShouldInterceptMethod(Type type, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        // decide whether you need to intercept your method here        
        return true;
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var generator = new ProxyGenerator();
    var options = new ProxyGenerationOptions(new CustomProxyGenerationHook());
    var fileCopierProxy = generator.CreateClassProxy(typeof(FileCopier),
                options
                new IInterceptor[] { // specify list of interceptors 
                    new ImpersonationInterceptor(), 
                    new LoggingInterceptor() 
                    }
                ) as FileCopier;
    fileCopierProxy.CopyFile("src", "dest");
}
```

Even if you've got a ton of classes and modifying them all by hand is not feasible, you can still work around it by opting for yet another technique called assembly weaving. [Project Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) is a good starting point, and this particular problem is best solved with [Virtuosity](https://github.com/Fody/Virtuosity) plugin - it basically rewrites your assembly on build to mark all methods virtual so you don't have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static T DecoratorActions<T>(string desc, Func<T> func)
        {
            return Log(desc, () => ImpersonateAndAct(func));
        }

        public static void DecoratorActions(string desc, Action action)
        {
            Log(desc, () => ImpersonateAndAct(action));
        }

        public string Read(string filepath)
        {
            return DecoratorActions($"Reading file at '{filepath}'",
                () => fileService.Read(filepath));
        }
```

Based on these very helpful answers I've been able to determine that, while I may not be able to automatically wrap all methods of a class. I can at least reduce boilplate code and separate concerns by using the Decorator Pattern instead of the standard inheritance.

As such I have a Log method which calls "Entering {methodName}" and "Exiting {methodName}" as well as try/catching for exceptions which it also logs before throwing.

Additionally an inline way of impersonating for a specific action in the ImpersonateAndAct method.

Both of these return type of T so they wrap calls to my decorated fileService without interfering with the products of those methods.

I marked @Xander as the correct answer as he was the chief inspiration for this approach but I wanted to leave an answer to share what I came up with.